# Knockout extender causing observable to return its default value on first pass regardless of input

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have defined a viewmodel called `model.customDifficultySettings`, a portion of which is shown below. It uses an extender called precision, which is just a renamed version of the extender example for rounding to X decimals shown in the Knockout.js documentation.

```js
ko.extenders.precision = function(target, precision) {
  //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
  var result = ko
    .pureComputed({
      read: target, //always return the original observables value
      write: function(newValue) {
        var current = target(),
          roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
          newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : +newValue,
          valueToWrite =
            Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

        //only write if it changed
        if (valueToWrite !== current) {
          target(valueToWrite);
        } else {
          //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
          if (newValue !== current) {
            target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .extend({ notify: "always" });

  //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
  result(target());

  //return the new computed observable
  return result;
};

model.customDifficultySettings = {
  econBase: ko
    .observable(0)
    .extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 750 }, precision: 3 }),
};
```

In a later `makeGame()` function we ensure our `model.customDifficultySettings.econBase()` observable matches the value of the selected difficulty value

```js
        model.customDifficultySettings.econBase(
          difficultyInfo[model.newGameDifficultyIndex() || 0].econBase
        );
        console.log(model.customDifficultySettings.econBase());
        console.log(difficultyInfo[model.newGameDifficultyIndex() || 0].econBase);
```

The value of `difficultyInfo[model.newGameDifficultyIndex()].econBase` on first run is 0.55. I would expect the console to either show both as 0.55, or if something had gone wrong, both as 0. Yet what's being returned is 0 for the observable but 0.55 for the value being fed into it.

If I query the observable from the console once the code has run, it returns the expected value of 0.55.

If the difficulty level is changed, which causes `makeGame()` to run again, all values are set correctly. It's only on the first run that this issue occurs.

I've tracked the issue back to the precision extender. Remove the extender and everything works as expected. But as I just copied the example code, I'm not entirely clear on what it does and therefore why this issue occurs.

As a workaround I could set all the observable default values to match the values of the default difficultly level, but I'd prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues appears to occur because I have declared a `rateLimit` first. If I reverse this and declare `precision` first, then everything works as expected. So my viewmodel now looks like this:

```js
model.customDifficultySettings = {
  econBase: ko
    .observable(0)
    .extend({ precision: 3, rateLimit: { timeout: 750 } }),
};
```